# How to extract data from graph in TABLE format in csv?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to scrape the data from this graph but in table format. [Link](https://www.instat.gov.al/en/sdgs/no-poverty/12-by-2030-reduce-at-least-by-half-the-proportion-of-men-women-and-children-of-all-ages-living-in-poverty-in-all-its-dimensions-according-to-national-definitions/121-proportion-of-population-living-below-the-national-poverty-line-by-sex-and-age/)

The problem is the structure of this graph, because it has months in the middle of the years, and I have tried some online scrapers but they consume too much time and sometimes I get distorted data.

More in detail I am using this software which I am citing because may help other people like me [app](https://plotdigitizer.com/#why-pro)

What do you suggest me to scrape and get the best results because I need to scrape a lot of these kind of graphs

Please I am new here, be polite, just tell me if i have to edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data for graph is embedded inside `<script>` tag, so to get them you can use next example:

```py
import json
import re

import pandas as pd
import requests


url = "https://www.instat.gov.al/en/sdgs/no-poverty/12-by-2030-reduce-at-least-by-half-the-proportion-of-men-women-and-children-of-all-ages-living-in-poverty-in-all-its-dimensions-according-to-national-definitions/121-proportion-of-population-living-below-the-national-poverty-line-by-sex-and-age/"

html_text = requests.get(url).text

# for map data:
# map_data = re.search(r"mapData=(.*?);<", html_text).group(1)
# print(map_data)

graph_data = re.search(r"graphsDataJson=(.*?);<", html_text).group(1)
graph_data = json.loads(graph_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(graph_data[0]["indicatorDataValues"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   year  value
0  2017   23.7
1  2018   23.4
2  2019   23.0
3  2020   21.8
```

Comment: This code functioned pretty well on Linux, but in MacOs  I get a repeated error saying: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: Idk what to do as I have installed pandas on terminal using `pip3 install pandas`

Comment: @Anisa Make sure you install `pandas` in the same environment as you run this script.

Answer (score 1):

I dont speak albanian(?), but this website transfers the data not in a json file (which is more common), but in a javascript file.

Have a look at the network explorer of your broswer and you will find the two urls that contain the data:

```
https://www.instat.gov.al/scripts/alb-geojson/gadm36_ALB_2.js
```

and

```
https://www.instat.gov.al/scripts/alb-geojson/gadm36_ALB_3.js
```

Simply copy it in your browser and you find nice structured data (which I dont understand myself without context)

**edit** There is a download button for xlsx file: `https://www.instat.gov.al/media/5789/goal-1_indicator_1_2_1-web.xlsx`

[image]

Comment: You saw the excel download button at the bottom?

https://www.instat.gov.al/media/5789/goal-1_indicator_1_2_1-web.xlsx

This gives you all available data in the graph as xlsx file, thats exactly what you need? The data is a little hidden in the last columns

Comment: I saw it but it is not for every SDG goal, just for 6 of them. take a look here [link](https://www.instat.gov.al/en/sdgs/good-health-and-well-being/31-by-2030-reduce-the-global-maternal-mortality-ratio-to-less-than-70-per-100-000-live-births/311-maternal-mortality-ratio/)

Comment: also the years do not correspond with their data sheet, because the graph has recent data not from 2012

Comment: I dont find a way, sorry. Since there are only 17 SDGs... why not extract the data manually?

Comment: Of course this was my plan B, but I was curios to know if it would be a way to automate the work. Anyway thank you :)